# Retrieve data from synchronous ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I have two pages. One page contains a form that will direct to a search results page when the user presses submit. The other page is the search results page. When the user hits submit, the URL of the search results page will say something like "www.theURL.com?pg=-thepagenum-". Afterwards, results will display and at the bottom will be a link saying display next x amount of pages and each page URL will have the "pg" portion incremented by 1. To do this, I thought of using a synchronous ajax post that will post to the search results page again.

Starting from the form page, I click submit and it loads the search results page populated with my results. However, when I click for the next page of results, I receive multiple php errors saying my $_POST variables are undefined. Is my logic in achieving my end result wrong? The success callback works but when it goes to that page, nothing is displayed but the php errors.

```
        //Display next page of results
        $("#next_results").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: "search_results.php?pg=<?php echo ++$_REQUEST['pg'] ?>&UI=<?php echo $_REQUEST['UI'] ?>",    
              <?php if(isset($_POST['keyword_search'])) { //Post info for keyword search ?>
                data: {keyword_search: 'true',
                keywords: <?php echo $_POST["keywords"]; ?> },
              <?php } //End if posting for keyword search
              else { //Post info for basic quick search ?>
                data: {'MOsearch_my_gender': gender_string , 
                min_age: <?php echo $_POST["min_age"]; ?> ,
                max_age: <?php echo $_POST["max_age"]; ?> ,
                MOsearch_my_orientation: orientation_string ,
                state_country: location_string ,
                only_zip: '<?php echo $_POST["only_zip"]; ?>' ,
                orderby: '<?php echo $_POST["orderby"]; ?>' ,
                logged_last_months: <?php echo $_POST["logged_last_months"]; ?> ,
                only_photos: pictures_only ,
                only_premium: premium_only ,
                only_online: online_only , 
                ChosenResultsPerPage: <?php echo $_POST["ChosenResultsPerPage"]; ?> },
              <?php } //End if posting for basic quick search ?>
              success: function () {alert("success")},
              async:false
        });
        });
    });
```

Comment: don't dump text from PHP directly into a JS context, you're likely to introduce JS syntax errors and kill the entire script. Use `echo json_encode(...)` instead, to guarantee production of valid javascript.

Comment: and have you done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($_POST)` to see what was received in PHP?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the quick reply. I'm not very experienced with PHP debugging. Where would I place var_dump($_POST) in my php files to see what is received in PHP?

Comment: Don't use `async: false` - it's incredibly bad practice.

Comment: Sorry I was unaware of that. What do you recommend using? I just want the same information I received from my form to be posted again to the search results page so that it can query for the right criteria and return the next set of results.

Comment: @crossfuse999: Make use of the `success` callback to respond to the AJAX request's completion, rather than making it synchronous and blocking the browser until it completes.

Comment: echo "<textarea cols='50' rows='10'>";var_dump($_POST);echo"</textarea>";

Comment: Thanks for @Thread7, I var_dumped $_POST and it showed that nothing was posted to the page. "array(0) []" . Am I posting via ajax wrong?